# Вывод файлов с определённым расширением

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которая выводит двумерный список файлов с определённым расширением:

```
 def selectfiles(self, dirs):

       return [filter(lambda i: '.hdf' in i  in i , os.listdir(dirs[x])) for x in
                                                                  range(len(dirs))]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как её лучше модифицировать, чтобы она выводила не только названия файлов, но и пути к ним?

Т.е. сейчас:

```
 [[tem1.txt, tem2.txt, tem3.txt],[tem10.txt, tem11.txt]]
```

А нужно:

```
 [[home/test/tem1.txt, home/test/tem2.txt, home/test/tem3.txt],[home/test10/tem10.txt, home/test10/tem11.txt]]
```

Comment: Добавляйте ещё свой dirs[x], как нибудь типа

    return [map(lambda i: dirs[x] + '/' + i, filter(lambda i: '.hdf' in i, os.listdir(dirs[x]))) for x in range(len(dirs))]

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё заработало как надо.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Find all files in directory with extension .txt in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3964681/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итого, функция из комментария:

```
@staticmethod
def selectfiles(dirs):
    return [map(lambda i: dirs[x] + '/' + i, filter(lambda i: '.hdf' in i, os.listdir(dirs[x]))) for x in range(len(dirs))]
```

Этот же алгоритм, но `pythonic way`:

```
@staticmethod
def select_files2(dirs):
    files = set()

    for dir in dirs:
        for file in os.listdir(dir):
            if file.endswith('.hdf'):
                files.add(os.path.join(dir, file))

    return list(files)
```

Comment: функции у вас разные результаты возвращают. Первая возвращает вложенный список (что OP хочет), вторая -- плоский набор файлов.

Comment: да, вы правильно заметили

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `selectfiles(dirs)` функции, которая принимает список директорий, лучше создать функцию `getfiles(dirname)`, которая принимает *одну* директорию и использовать [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), чтобы применить её к списку `dirs` всех директорий: `list2D = map(getfiles, dirs)`.

Чтобы получить из директории все файлы  с заданным расширением:

```
import os
from glob import glob

def getfiles(dirname):
    return glob(os.path.join(dirname, '*.hdf'))
```

Если `dirname` не содержит файловых шаблонов, то это равнозначно:

```
def getfiles(dirname):
    return [os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            for filename in os.listdir(dirname)
            if filename.endswith('.hdf')]
```

В более общем случае (когда задан произвольный шаблон для имени файла), можно использовать [`glob.glob1()`, `fnmatch.filter()` функции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3971553/4279).

Или с помощью [`pathlib` модуля](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

list2D = [list(Path(dirname).glob('*.hdf')) for dirname in dirs]
```