# Выполнение одного кода на много файлов csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Как сделать так, чтобы подобный код выполнялся ко всем файлам .csv в папке, а названия сохраненный файлов бралось из названия открытого файла и + total в конце, например. Смысл в том, что из csv файла мы делаем операцию вычитания между столбцами.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/222.csv',
                sep=',', encoding='latin1',
                parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True,
                index_col='Date')

a["total"] = a["1"] - a["2"]
a["total"].to_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/data'+'_total.csv')
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод файлов с определённым расширением](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295845/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это достаточно просто:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_mask = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv'

files = glob.glob(file_mask)

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1')
    df['total'] = df['1'] - df['2']
    new_fn = '{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f))
    df.to_csv(new_fn)
```

Называть столбцы рекомендуют строками (число в виде строки - плохой вариант) без пробелов и спец. символов, в противном случае некоторые методы не будут работать. Например следующий (`"chained"`) код будет работать с обычными именами:

```
for f in files:
    pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1') \
      .eval("total = Close - Open", inplace=False) \
      .to_csv('{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f)))
```

а со столбцами `1` и `2` работать не будет - `NumExpr` (который используется Pandas методами `eval()` и `query()`) не сможет отличить числа от имен столбцов:

```
for f in files:
    pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1') \
      .eval("total = '1' - '2'", inplace=False) \
      .to_csv('{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f)))
```